# passing xml as a string to webservice causes complete failure

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, asmx

I am hosting a .net webservice written in c#. In one of my web methods, I'm expecting a few inbound parameters, all of which are strings. The final string is actually a string of xml (I started out doing a dataset for this, but read this was a big no-no, so went this route instead).

The xml (as a string) is incredibly simple.

```
<FriendsArray><Friend><FriendSocialID>123456789</FriendSocialID><FriendName>Test Test</FriendName><AvatarImage>https://www.imagelocation.com</AvatarImage><FriendGender></FriendGender></Friend></FriendsArray>
```

With the `<FriendsArray>` being the bounder, and the `<Friend>` node being repeated n times. On the webservice side, I take this string, serialize it into xml and deal with the data.

When the webservice is run locally on the server in Visual Studio, it works perfectly, no issues. When the webservice is run locally and attached to a test calling program that simply emulates passing these parameters, including the FriendArray to the webservice, again, right as rain, no issues, works perfectly.

Real world scenario of calling the webservice foreign (either via emulation, like SoapUI or XMLSpy, or directly from the app that is meant to call it) it bombs the service. No error is returned, or empty response object, it completely fails, and returns nothing.

The second I remove this FriendArray (its optional on the codebehind), it works perfectly.

Is there some inherent issue to doing this the way I am trying to? If so, is there an easy alternate way that requires not a huge amount of recoding? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of web service is it? ASMX?

Comment: Yes, its a pretty straightforward .asmx webservice

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the XML as it is. There must be some problem with how you were processing it. Can you show some of the code in your service?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently "<" and ">" are reserved in XML. Wasn't aware of that. All I had to do was escape them with `&lt;` and `&gt;` in the string, and it works perfectly now.

Comment: How else would the parser be able to tell where tags begin and end? Good job debugging your own code though.

Comment: @Oren sometimes the simplest solutions are the hardest to come by. It was staring me straight in the face and I didn't even realize it.

Comment: Yea, that happens surprisingly often. Hope my comment wasn't snarky--was just trying to point out that reserving those charachters is necessary for the parser to be able to work its magic.